# C# Castle Windsor DI with LoggingFacility and core.logging doesn't log Exception

Tags: c#, logging, castle-windsor, nlog

For a project I'm using Castle Windsor DI (new for me). The `Castle.Core.Logging` namespace with its interface `Logger` has these methods (also with Debug, Error etc):

- `void Fatal(string message, Exception exception);`
- `void Fatal(string message);`

However, when I'm using the methods with the exception parameter, it only logs the message, not the exception. I can't seem to figure out why it only logs the message, maybe I missed a setting? Currently NLog is used for logging. The logger is injected in a base class like this:

```
public ILogger Log { get; set; } = NullLogger.Instance;
```

This setup is from [NLog and Castle Logging Facility for Logging](http://hwyfwk.com/blog/2013/10/06/nlog-and-castle-logging-facility-for-logging/)

Comment: Please share your NLog config. Are us using `${exception}`?

Answer (score 2):

You can customize the layout and the content of the messages Nlog will give you by setting this inside the Nlog config file.
For this you could write for example:

```
<targets>
    <!-- write logs to file -->
    <target xsi:type="File" name="logfile" fileName="c:\temp\console-example.log"
            layout="${longdate}|${level}|${message} |${all-event-properties}${exception:format=tostring}" />
    <target xsi:type="Console" name="logconsole"
            layout="${longdate}|${level}|${message} |${all-event-properties}${exception:format=tostring}" />
  </targets>
```

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-.NET-Core-2---Console-application